# Emissive material from white texture

Tags: unity, textures, materials

I have texture with black and white shapes.

I would like that white parts are emissive and black parts are transparent/glass.

How to make such material ?

Comment: Presumably you tried using the Unity Standard material in Transparent mode, setting its alpha value very low, and adding your texture to the Emissive channel, right? Did something not work the way you expected it to?

Comment: no, it didn't but maybe I didn't set up uv map in blender properly.

Comment: Great. Edit your post to show us what you've tried and explain exactly what went wrong. We'll be able to help you solve the problem much better once we know what problem you're having.

Comment: I did it. And your material setup is the one I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Try writing an Answer describing what you did to make it work then. :)